# UWP MediaElement URI behavior

Tags: file, uwp, uri, mediaelement

I have a UWP with a MediaElement that is used to play a video. I have a ReactiveProperty in ViewModel used for binding a Uri to the MediaElement Source property. The Uri is created using a string in the format "ms-appdata:/local/..." I also used a Uri type binding property with property change notification and observed the same behavior so doubt this is attributable to binding with ReactiveProperty.

When I run it I get a standard invalid file or path message displayed in MediaElement over a white background. However, when I create the Uri in the MediaElement Load event in codebehind and set the Source property to it there it works.

Even more odd is that when I bind via ReactiveProperty and examine the MediaElement Source property from the codebehind Load event it no longer shows the Uri format that had been specified. Instead it shows "File:///..."

I'm not sure if this is specific to MediaElement or not but I can't understand both why the Uri format seems to change and why it should make a difference setting binding property in ViewModel or setting it directly on MediaElement in codebehind Load event.

I'm hoping this might ring a bell with someone. I have left the code working with the codebehind approach but if someone needs the code I could change it back and provide code examples. Hope I don't need to...

Thanks if anyone can comment. Even better if someone might have encountered and resolves such an issue.

Comment: It occurred to me that this might be caused due to MediaElement being in a DataTemplate that is resolved using a TemplateSelector so that the binding somehow occurs before the MediaElement is loaded. But I'd think that it would play when loaded or after clicking play media control. And that doesn't account for the change in the URI format which might be a significant factor. I'm stumped and thinking it might be a bug.

Comment: If you have the example, please share it. Without any code, it's hard to say why you have this problem.

Comment: I will have to reconstruct it, but will get to it. I was not working with source control at the time as I usually do or else I could recover the prior level of the source.